# tensorflow fit_generator during training shows some error in validation data

Tags: tensorflow

This is the code:

```
train_generator=train.flow_from_directory('data/train',target_size=(size,size),batch_size='64',
                                          class_mode='binary')
validation_generator=valid.flow_from_directory('data/valid', target_size=(size,size), batch_size='64',
                                               class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(train_generator,steps_per_epoch=31,epochs=4,validation_data=validation_generator,validation_steps=4)
```

But for some reasons it shows an error in the `fit_generator` line. I checked various answers but nothing seems to work. I am having 2000 training data, and 300 validation data.

Comment: Can you include the error message?

Comment: You need to include the complete error messages and the code that produces it.